# AEM Page Export, not working for non-admin users

Tags: synchronization, export, aem

Using references from [The Page Exporter](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-2/sites/administering/using/page-exporter.html) and [Mobile with Content Sync](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-2/mobile/using/phonegap-contentsync.html)
, I have implemented page exporter configuration.

With this, in admin login, http://localhost:4502/content/something.export.zip works fine. This downloads a ZIP file with all HTML, images, CSS and JS.

But with any other login, even though the user is of administrator group will only download empty zip file.

Please help resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use the system user instead of a normal user. Make sure the system user or the "everyone" group has the appropriate permissions over "/content " and other relevant paths.

Answer (score 0):

The issue stated seems to be related to permission. As described in [Adobe Forum](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2515034), /var/contentsync permission is also important.